# UART terminal garbage value RA2A1 series MCU

Tags: serial-port, uart, sprint

I used RA2A1 Renesas series MCU and E2 studio & Moboxtream Serial terminal

I try to print the float value on the terminal via UART functionality after every 5 sec.
so I used the timer interrupt and check UART transmission completed via UART  interrupt call back. So It looks like a nested interrupt.
UART callback has higher priority i.e 0 while 5-sec periodic timer interrupt has lower priority i.e. 1.
I used 4800 as baud rate and channel 1. I used another baud rate but not successful.
Sometimes it Prints properly sometimes not. How to solved it?
[UART Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0gJr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using FSP API for coding RA2A1 Renesas MCU with UART functionality
There are two API i.e R_SCI_UART_Open and R_SCI_UART_Close
so when ever you wanna send data first OPEN the UART peripherals and after sending data you have to close it